# Identity of $8\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)$

Tags: trigonometry

I know this probably has a simple answer, but I am having trouble understanding the steps to find the identity for this problem.

This is the answer I was provided:

$$8\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) = 2\sin^2(2x)$$

The closest Identity I can find is:

$$\sin(x)\cos(y) = 1/2[\sin(x+y) + \sin(x-y)]$$

Which would give

$$\frac 1 2 [\sin(x+x) + \sin(x-x)] = \frac 1 2 [\sin(2x)+\sin(0)] = \frac 1 2 [\sin(2x)+1]$$

Which plugged in would give:
$4(\sin(2x) + 1)$

Which clearly isn't what I'm looking for... tell me what I'm doing wrong please!

Comment: Can you find an identity that involves $\sin(2x)$?

Comment: You've made a mistake. sin(0) = 0, it's cos(0) = 1. Then the formua reduces to sin(x)cos(x) = 1/2*sin(2x), which should let you get the desired result

Comment: @JasonCarr Ah! The simple mistakes get me :| that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following identity, it's pretty straightforward:
$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\sin^2(2x)=4\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$$
$$2\sin^2(2x)=8\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

**HInt:**
Use $\sin(2x)=2\sin{x}\cos{x}$

Answer (score 2):

For all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ we have
$$
\sin (x+y) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y,
$$
which can either be proved or be as a starting point. To prove it we need a few axioms; see for example Apostol's calculus.

Now, if $x \in \Bbb{R}$, then applying the theorem above gives 
$$
\sin (x+x) = \sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x;
$$
and you can continue from here.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, your mistake, $\color{red}{\sin 0\ne 1}$

using trig identity $2\sin A\cos A=\sin 2A$, 
$$8\sin^2 x\cos^2 x=2(2\sin x\cos x)^2$$
$$=2(\sin (2x))^2$$$$=2\sin^2 (2x)$$